# How to use matplotlib in Kivy with kv file?

Tags: canvas, plot, kivy

I am trying to plot a matplotlib chart on my kivy App.
I found this on internet

```
plt.plot([1, 23, 2, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box

MyApp().run()
```

It works perfectly for me but when I use

```
 box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
```

it plots ALL the plt.plots of my python file and I would like to plot only one ! I already tried to name my plot like

```
fig=plt.plot(..)
```

and then to do

```
 box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf(fig)))
```

But it doesn't work !
Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Have you tried the simple example you posted to make sure it works?

Comment: Yes it works ! But I want to declare the BoxLayout in the kivy file instead of the python file